# how to solve tan(pi(cot(x))) = cot(pi(tan(x)))

Tags: trigonometry

I got as far as this
$\cot(\frac{\pi}{2} - \pi \cdot \cot(x)) = \cot( \pi \cdot \tan(x))$

But when I simplify it further I eventually get $\cot(x) + \tan(x) = \frac{1}{2}$

Which has no solutions.

I have a feeling I need to do something with this:
$\tan(mx) = \cot(nx)$ and general solution to this is $x = \frac{1}{m+n}(r\pi + \pi/2)$

The solution is probably really obvious as usual

TIA

Comment: Not at all a simple problem.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to solve this? According to wolframalpha, the solutions are   $x = n\pi + \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{2m \pm \sqrt{4m^2+4m-15}+1}{4}\right)$ , where $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $39 - 4m^2 - 4m \pm (2m+1)\sqrt{4m^2+4m-15} \neq 0$. Doesn't seem "really obvious" to me.

Comment: $\cot u=\cot v\iff u=v+k\pi$, $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Working through Loney trigonometry which is over a 100 years old. I kinda like the book, and the previous examples were not very difficult at all. So that is why I assumed the solution was probably relatively simple. But it seems this book likes to randomly ramp up the difficulty in between exercises. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After your simplification, your equation is equivalent to
$$\pi\tan x=\frac\pi2-\pi\cot x+k\pi\iff \tan x+\cot x=\frac12+k\iff \frac{2}{\sin2x}=\frac12+k$$
So the solutions are the valid (and non null) solutions of
$$\sin 2x=\frac{4}{1+2k}$$
$k\in\mathbb Z$ has to verify $1+2k\ge4$ or $1+2k\le -4$, so $k\ge2$ or $k\le -3$. So the solutions are
$$S=\left\{\frac{1}{2}\arcsin\frac{4}{1+2k}+l\pi,\ k\le -3\text{ or }k\ge2,\ l\in\mathbb Z\right\}\cup \left\{l\pi-\frac{1}{2}\arcsin\frac{4}{1+2k},\ k\le -3\text{ or }k\ge2,\ l\in\mathbb Z\right\}$$

Comment: thanks for answer, but I think this question was a bit too difficult for me. Is it possible to quickly show why tan x + cot x can be converted to 2/sin 2x ? I sort of lost you there.

Comment: $\tan x+\cot x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x} + \frac{\cos x}{\sin x} = \frac{\sin^2x+\cos^2x}{\sin x\cos x} = \frac{1}{\frac12\sin 2x}=\frac{2}{\sin 2x}$

Comment: much appreciated

edit: shouldn't it be $sin 2x = \frac{1+2k}{4}$

Comment: No. Rewrite the equation.